# Select() decline in performance

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm working on small app which is written in `c# .net core` and I'm populating one prop in a code because that information is not available in database, code looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>> GetData(Request request)
{
    IQueryable<Product> query = _context.Products;

    var products = await query.ToListAsync();

    // WARNING - THIS SOLUTION LOOKS EXPENCIVE TO ME!

    return MapDataAsDTO(products).Select(c =>
    {
        c.HasBrandStock = products.Any(cc => cc.ParentProductId == c.Id);
        return c;
        });
    }
}

private IEnumerable<ProductDTO> MapDataAsDTO(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    return products.Select(p => MapData(p)).ToList();
}
```

What is bothering me here is this code:

```
 return MapDataAsDTO(products).Select(c =>
 {
    c.HasBrandStock = data.Any(cc => cc.ParentProductId == c.Id);
    return c;
 });
}
```

I've tested it on like `300k` rows and it seems slow, I'm wondering is there a better solutions in this situations?

Thanks guys!

Cheers

Comment: what exactly is `data` ? and where is it defined?

Comment: I would guess that it is slow because of all those `ToList()`. They force .NET to load everything to memory instead of operating in the database.

Comment: ` await query.ToListAsync();` that loads *all* products in memory. `MapDataAsDTO` works on that List<Product>. Create a *single* query instead and execute it just once with `ToListAsync()`. If EF complains that it can't convert the query to SQL, *don't* use `ToList` to cover this up - that's what makes things slower.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So basically I should avoid ToList instead of that I should use ToListAsync() ?

Comment: You should profile your code to know **exactly** where the time is being consumed. All else is guesswork and will almost certainly lead to you optimizing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

First up, this method is loading *all* products, and generally that is a bad idea unless you are guaranteeing that the total number of records will remain reasonable, and the total size of those records will be reasonable. If the system can grow, add support for server-side pagination now. (Page # and Page size, leveraging `Skip` & `Take`)  300k products is not a reasonable number to be loading all data in one hit. Any way you skin this cat it will be slow, expensive, and error prone due to server load without paging. One user making a request on the server will need to have the DB server allocate for and load up 300k rows, transmit that data over the wire to the app server, which will allocate memory for those 300k rows, then transmit that data over the wire to the client who literally does not need those 300k rows at once. What do you think happens when 10 users hit this page? 100? And what happens when it's "to slow" and they start hammering the F5 key a few times. >:)

Second, `async` is not a silver bullet. It doesn't make queries faster, it actually makes them a bit slower. What it does do is allow your web server to be more responsive to other requests while those slower queries are running. Default to synchronous queries, get them running as efficiently as possible, then for the larger ones that are justified, switch them to asynchronous. MS made `async` extremely easy to implement, perhaps too easy to treat as a default. Keep it simple and synchronous to start, then re-factor methods to async as needed.

From what I can see you want to load all products into DTOs, and for products that are recognized as being a "parent" of at least one other product, you want to set their DTO's HasBrandStock to True.  So given product IDs 1 and 2, where 2's parent ID is 1, the DTO for Product ID 1 would have a HasBrandStock True while Product ID 2 would have HasBrandStock = False.

One option would be to tackle this operation in 2 queries:

```
var parentProductIds = _context.Products
    .Where(x => x.ParentProductId != null)
    .Select(x => x.ParentProductId)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

var dtos = _context.Products
    .Select(x => new ProductDTO
    {
       ProductId = x.ProductId,
       ProductName = x.ProductName,
       // ...
       HasBrandStock = parentProductIds.Contains(x.ProductId)
    }).ToList();
```

I'm using a manual `Select` here because I don't know what your MapAsDto method is actually doing. I'd highly recommend using Automapper and it's `ProjectTo<T>` method if you want to simplify the mapping code. Custom mapping functions can too easily hide expensive bugs like `ToList` calls when someone hits a scenario that EF cannot translate.

The first query gets a distinct list of just the Product IDs that are the parent ID of at least one other product. The second query maps out all products into DTOs, setting the HasBrandStock based on whether each product appears in the parentProductIds list or not.

This option will work if a relatively limited number of products are recognized as "parents". That first list can only get so big before it risks crapping out being too many items to translate into an `IN` clause.

The better option would be to look at your mapping. You have a ParentProductId, does a product entity have an associated ChildProducts collection?

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual Product ParentProduct { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ChildProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}

public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
       HasKey(x => x.ProductId);
       HasOptional(x => x.ParentProduct)
          .WithMany(x => x.ChildProducts)
          .Map(x => x.MapKey("ParentProductId")); 
    }
}
```

This example maps the ParentProductId without exposing a field in the entity (recommended). Otherwise, if you do expose a ParentProductId, substitute the `.Map(...)` call with `.HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentProductId)`.

This assumes EF6 as per your tags, if you're using EF Core then you use `HasForeignKey("ParentProductId")` in place of `Map(...)` to establish a shadow property for the FK without exposing a property. The entity configuration is a bit different with Core.

This allows your queries to leverage the relationship between parent products and any related children products. Populating the DTOs can be accomplished with one query:

```
var dtos = _context.Products
    .Select(x => new ProductDTO
    {
       ProductId = x.ProductId,
       ProductName = x.ProductName,
       // ...
       HasBrandStock = x.ChildProducts.Any()
    }).ToList();
```

This leverages the relationship to populate your DTO and it's flag in one pass. The caveat here is that there is now a cyclical relationship between product and itself represented in the entity. This means don't feed entities to something like a serializer. That includes avoiding adding entities as members of DTOs/ViewModels.